# Borland Starteam: How to re -check-in a file from a frozen labeled configuration to current configuration with history

Tags: starteam

Borland Starteam: How to re -check-in a file from a frozen labeled configuration to current configuration with history?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to go to that frozen labeled configuration (View->Select Configuration->Labeled Configuration) and pick that label.  Then what you are seeing should be files as of that label.  You could then checkout the file you wanted from that label.

Then go back to the current configuration (View->Select Configuration->Current Configuration) and check-in your file (you will have to do a Forced Check-In since it will show as Out of Date status).  In the check-in comments you may want to mention that you pulled that file forwards from that label.

You will not lose any of the history between the label and your check-in.

Comment: I don't think this will work out. Because when we switch to current configuration (once after checking-out the file from old labelled config), the file becomes "Not In View". It can't be "Out Of Date". Hence we will be able to "Add" this file as a "New file" to the current configuration.

BTW, I didn't try the response from "Jeremy Murray". I will have to see whether that will work or not. I will check and come back again.

Answer (score 0):

If the file does not exist in the current configuration, you can share the file from the labeled config to current - just have the view open in two separate windows.  This will retain all of the version history.

There is a hiccup in that it will not allow you to share the file into the same folder as it originally existed (as of 2008R2).  Just share the file into a different folder then move it.

All history is retained.  Note that the new instance is a share, so you may want to check the reference tab before branching to make sure it will do what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Based on GanYo's comment to the question -

The problem **is not** the fact that the file is sitting in a frozen label -
the real problem is that the file was **deleted**.

You cannot "bring back to life" a file that was deleted,
but you can "go back in time" to see it's history (as mentioned by **[Dougman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4311/dougman)**).

**The only solution supported by Borland is this:**

1. **Set-Configuration** to a time (or label) just before the file was deleted
   (this should allow you access to the latest version of the file with all its history).
2. **Check-out** all the different revisions of the file, one-by-one, keeping them in unique names
   until you have the complete list of revisions.
   (best is to append the revision-number to the name of each revision to the file being saved locally)
3. **Set-Configuration** back to '*Current*'.
4. **Check-in** the complete history of the file, starting with the oldest version of the file,
   and going forward, until you have imported all the file-revisions in the correct sequence.
   (you have to rename each revision of the file to its original name before you check it in, of course)

Having said that, *you really need to think if this is worth it*, because:

- This "restore" process **does not bring back**:

  - the *comments* of each revision
  - the *CR-links* that were attached to each revision
  - the *Lables* that were attached to each revision
- The file's history was there all along, and is available via '*Set Configuration*' - why duplicate it?

**Bottom line**:
It is probably best just to restore the latest version of the file,
mentioning in the comment that it was deleted accidentally and that its history can be reviewed
by doing 'Set Configuration' to ...